how to track only the first time conversion for the user on my site in GA4
I would like to ask how to track conversion/event set in GA4 only for a new user on the site , i.e.  to count only the first time conversion for the user
I set event whcih is trigger when the button "Confirm" is clikced, but GA4 tracks the event each time when the unser clicks on "Confirms". I would like this to be done only once and then not to count is as event anymore.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The easiest and least reliable way to do this is to limit it to fire once per pageview. That's done in the tag config in GTM.
To make it even more protected, you can use cookies. Set a cookie on firing the config tag and check if it's set in the triggering condition.

thanks  for the ideas. Limiting an event to fire only once per page view does not completely address the problem. This is because if a user returns to the site after 2-3 days, the event will fire again, which is not the desired outcome. The goal is to count the event only once per user for their lifetime.
But I like the proposal for the cookies, I think this would solve by problem.

This is the proposed solution by Chatgpt. Is that the same configuration you propose or you have another?
Create a JavaScript Variable to Set the Cookie:
Go to Variables in GTM and create a new User-Defined Variable. Choose Custom JavaScript.
Create a JavaScript Variable to Check the Cookie:
Create another Custom JavaScript variable to check if the cookie exists:
Create a Trigger to Check the Cookie:
Go to Triggers and create a new trigger.
Choose Custom Event.
Set the condition to check if the cookie variable equals "" (empty),

yes, that's right. this particular issue is trivial enough to be correctly handled by chatgpt. It's a common solution. Some issues with how it suggest to have the trigger as a custom event. That's not  applicable to your situation cuz you already have the trigger and you don't need to make another, but hey, maybe your prompt didn't provide that context, so it generated a generic response.

After a discussion with my colleagues, I understood that the cookies have been updated to more secure versions, and GTM may not always recognize if the cookies are set. So, could you please guide me on how to implement this correctly with the new secure cookies? Any detailed steps or best practices would be greatly appreciated. Or another proposal. Thanks

cookies updated to more secure version? Either you're talking about third party cookie deprecation which has no relation to this since this would be a first-party cookie or I don't know about this new cookie feature. If you could link to it that would be great.
